# How to end Periodic Updates to a Windows 8 Live Tile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've seen lots of examples of how to begin Periodic Updates to a live tile in Windows 8, e.g:

```
PeriodicUpdateRecurrence recurrence = PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.Hour;
System.Uri url = new System.Uri(polledUrl);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().StartPeriodicUpdate(url, recurrence);
```

However, how do you undo this?  I've added an app setting to disable the live tile updates but I can't find code to remove the polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PeriodicUpdateRecurrence recurrence = PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.Hour;
System.Uri url = new System.Uri(polledUrl);
var tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();

tileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdate(url, recurrence);

// ...

tileUpdater.StopPeriodicUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the answer by browsing through the Intellisense options.

To revert a tile to its default state, i.e. not live, use:

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
```

Hope this helps someone - it wasn't easy to find in any of the Windows Dev Centre Quickstarts.

Comment: `Clear` only removes what is currently being displayed on the tile. Periodic updates will continue to be delivered. From your question, it sounds like you want to both clear the tile content and stop polling (`StopPeriodicUpdate`).